# I need to create a SPFx web part which looks like tab and click on each tab it will show out of the box web part like organization chart etc

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I need to create SPFx web part that will be displayed in SharePoint modern page.

When I click on tabs it will show out of the box web part like organization structure, news, etc.

Any suggestions?